# How to let the Javascript run at the last process in a page with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, multithreading, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I got into a trouble that when the Page Loads, then my Javascript runs and the JS Calendar loads after my JS. Thus, my JS doesn't affect to JS Calendar.

> 1.Page Loads
>
> **2.My JS runs**
>
> 3.Something (Other JS) goes here
>
> **4.JS Calendar starts**

What I want here is to let my **JS runs after the JS Calendar**. Some suggested me to use **`on()`** but I don't know that is the best solution or there are other solutions.

The JSFIDDLE below works very well with browsers but it doesn't work with SharePoint 2010.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView">
<div class="ms-acal-header">
<div>
    <table class="ms-acal-month">
    </table>
    <div class="ms-acal-vlink">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Add" evtid="new_item">
                        <img border="0" src="/_layouts/images/caladd.gif">Add</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var abc = $("#AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView").find('a[title="Add"][evtid="new_item"]').hover(
          function () {
              $(this).attr('href', 'http://share/Lists/Calendar.aspx?P=P1');
          }
        );
    });
```

**JSFIDDLE:** **http://jsfiddle.net/nALMw/**

I have attempted with jQuery `on()` but It didn't work with my SharePoint 2010:

```
$( "#AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView div div table" ).on( "click", function() {
    var abc = $("#AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView").find('a[title="Add"] [evtid="new_item"]').hover(
        function () {
            $(this).attr('href', 'http://share/Lists/Calendar.aspx?P=P1');
        }
    );
});
```

or

```
$( "#AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView" ).on( "click", '.ms-acal-vlink' , function() {
    var abc = $("#AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView").find('a[title="Add"] [evtid="new_item"]').hover(
        function () {
            $(this).attr('href', 'http://share/Lists/Calendar.aspx?P=P1');
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: What causes the calendar to load?  You need to investigate the code that loads the calendar and find if there are notification events when it is done loading.  Also, what is your JS that wants to wait until after the calendar trying to do?  Is it just trying to install event handlers or do more than that?

Comment: JSCalendar may (should) have an event that gets triggered when it loads. Something like `load:` or `onload:` or `ready:` that you can provide a function to--a function that holds all the code that depends on the calendar being ready. The documentation would tell you. That function would get either get passed in as a parameter when the calendar is initialized or there is an event like `calendarReady` that you can use to do `$(document).on('calendarReady'),...` just like you're doing with click events in `$("#AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView").on("click",...` in your example above.

Comment: **@jfriend00**: I think my problem here is a timing issue, because my JS always runs before the JS Calendar. To be more specific, I have tested by viewing source on the page and search for title="Add", I don't find it. After JS Calendar runs completely, the Add link gets generated when the user is hovering over the date. Therefore, my JS doesn't affect to JS Calendar...

Comment: Maybe try adding the js to the calendar.aspx page as either a web part or in the actual page (using SP Designer). That way that script you want to run after the calendar loads can only do so when the page content is delivered.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, please let me know if it doesn't work with your SharePoint or anything goes wrong :-).

```
$(document).on("click", "#AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView .ms-acal-vlink", function () {
        var find_aTag = $(("#AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView").find('a[title="Add"]'));
        find_aTag.attr("href", "http://share/Lists/Calendar.aspx?P=P1");
    });
```

or **MdMazzotti**'s method

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("spReady");

function spReady() {
  $('.s4-ba').on('click', '.ms-acal-item a', function(){ 
     console.log('clicked');  
  });
}
```

Comment: Does the above method works in SharePoint 2016 ?.. I tried but not working.