# How to run the JS with on() function with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After the JS Calendar starts completely, the HTML below appears and I would like to run my JS with `AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView` attribute. However, it doesn't work at all.

Otherwise, is there any solution for my problem that I need to make sure that I can use the `AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView` attribute to run my JS?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView">
    <div class="ms-acal-header">
    <div>
        <table class="ms-acal-month">
        </table>
        <div class="ms-acal-vlink">
            <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Add" evtid="new_item">
                    <img border="0" src="/_layouts/images/caladd.gif">Add</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
</div></div></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$( "#AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView div div table" ).on( "click", function() {
    var abc = $("#AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView").find('a[title="Add"] [evtid="new_item"]').hover(
        function () {
            $(this).attr('href', 'http://share/Lists/Calendar.aspx?P=P1');
        }
    );
});
```

or

```
$( "#AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView" ).on( "click", '.ms-acal-vlink' , function() {
    var abc = $("#AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView").find('a[title="Add"] [evtid="new_item"]').hover(
        function () {
            $(this).attr('href', 'http://share/Lists/Calendar.aspx?P=P1');
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23258664/how-to-let-the-javascript-run-at-the-last-process-in-a-page-with-javascript) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23259578/how-to-run-the-js-with-on-function-with-javascript) also by PMay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView div div table` doesn't exist when you when you run that selector, so there are no elements for `on` to bind the event handler too, instead you should delegate it to an ancestor, such as `document`, or the element which that html is being inserted into:

```
$(document).on(
  "click",
  "#AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView .ms-acal-vlink",
  function () {
    var abc = $("#AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView").find('a[title="Add"] [evtid="new_item"]').hover(
        function () {
            $(this).attr('href', 'http://share/Lists/Calendar.aspx?P=P1');
        }
    );
  }
);
```

There is a good explanation of this in the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events):

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on(). To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page, select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is placed into the page. Or, use delegated events to attach an event handler, as described next.
>
> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This element could be the container element of a view in a Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the event handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. The document element is available in the head of the document before loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without waiting for the document to be ready.

Comment: It's awesome, that works well. Thank you very much for both your code and tutorial :-)